# Elasticsearch dependency not working, It does not show on my imports is there correct version for this?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Is there something wrong on how I import the elasticsearch dependency?

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.DeleteIndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.AcknowledgedResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;

import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.metrics.Cardinality;
import org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.search.collapse.CollapseBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.search.sort.FieldSortBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortOrder;
```

Here is my dependencies in build.gradle file:

```
implementation group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client', version: '7.4.2'
implementation group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-client', version: '7.4.2'
implementation group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport', version: '7.4.2'
implementation group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '7.4.2'
```

I have tried different version but it is not working what is the correct approach for this. Thanks

Comment: Please include your code/config in your question as code (text with code tags) instead of links to offsite images.

Comment: I've just edited my post.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens when you compile / run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: My IDE says " Cannot resolve symbol 'elasticsearch' " when I import it.